Is everything in Next.js cached by default, and when should I use TanStack Query?
I've been learning Next.js and watched a video where the author mentions that Next.js handles caching for SSR/SSG and client-side navigation automatically. However, I’m wondering if everything is cached by default, or if there are scenarios where caching needs to be managed manually?
Additionally, when would it make sense to use TanStack Query (formerly React Query) in a Next.js project? The video suggests it’s unnecessary for typical data fetching since Next.js handles it, but I’m unsure about situations where TanStack Query would still be helpful.
I’d appreciate some clarification on these points.
